# Struts2 - OGNL parameterized name

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, el, ognl

I have a generic jsp which is in charge of printing some values, the values depends on a parameter.

For example, I have an object **car** with and attribute **color** and a object **house** with the same attribute, I want to use the same jsp receiveng the name of the object as a parameter.

```xml
<jsp:include page="/jsp/prv/generic/PaintColor.jsp" >
    <jsp:param name="element" value="car" />
</jsp:include>
```

So, I want to print the value of car color. I try to do it like this:

```xml
<s:set var="propertyName">${param.element}.color<s:set/>

<s:property value="%{#attr.propertyName}" />
```

It doesnt work, but if I do

```xml
<s:textfield name="%{#attr.propertyName}"/>
```

it works perfect.

How can I use the parametrized name in avalue?

Comment: If you are setting value in set tag then there no need to retrieve it with `attr` expression, use `#propertyName`.

Comment: In Struts2  JSPs are treated as actions, so you can use `#parameters` prefix.

Answer (score -1):

I finally solve it accesing the value from a java scriptlet

Comment: Did you try `#attr[propertyName]`? In any case, resorting to scriptlets is the worst of both worlds.

Comment: @DaveNewton I seem to have the same problem. Can you please help? Check the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067412/struts2-jsp-el-concatenation-doesnt-seem-to-work)