# Struts2 - JSP EL - Concatenation doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, el, ognl

Trying to figure out this issue for a long time...

I am setting a variable with a value from an Object.

```jsp
<s:set name="bodyText" value='First Name "myObject.name"'/>
```

and trying to print it in the following ways.. None of these works.

```jsp
"${bodyText}"
"<s:property value="#bodyText" />"
"${#bodyText}"
"%{bodyText}"
"%{#bodyText}"
```

Not sure the problem is with

I tried the following as well:

```jsp
<s:set name="bodyText" value='First Name "${myObject.name}"'/>
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value attribute should be an object. OGNL uses quotes to delimit a string object, other quotes should be escaped.

And use `var` attribute for variable name.

```jsp
<s:set var="bodyText" value="'First Name \"myObject.name\"'"/>
<s:property value="bodyText" />
```

Comment: Is this just bodyText or #bodyText when printing?

Comment: Why do we need single quotes as well in addition to double quotes?!?! It works though!!!

Comment: With quotas we define a string object, then it can print. If you remove single quotas nothing will be printed. Everything enclosed double quotas (attribute) treated as OGNL expression and fails to return an object. Also in OGNL expression you can't use EL, see previous error.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the edit, and good night! @KevinRave You are welcome!

Comment: @Roman C  I did not know the s:set value could be used in this way  _Everything enclosed double quotas (attribute) treated as OGNL_ I can not find this technique any where. can you please let me know if this is a documented feature and where is it in struts site, may be there are more things there which we are not aware of them!